# Nginx Config for ws://<ip>:<port>

Tags: nginx, web-server, socket, websocket

I have a domain i call it `<domain>` and ip call `<ip>` and port `<my-local-port>`, i wan't using nginx on my server (dns binded to my server success), my problem is that reverse proxy ws:// protocole to my server i send my request in two link:

- `https://<ip>:<my-local-port>`
- `ws://<ip>:<my-local-port>`

for https i configurate nginx as:

```
server {
      listen       443;
      server_name  <domain>    www.<domain> ;

      location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:<my-local-port>;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      }
}
```

i bind `https://<domain>` into my local port `<my-local-port>`.

**how can i bind  `ws://<domain>` into local port `<my-local-port>` ?**

Answer (score 0):

First define a websocket upstream:

```
upstream websocket {
   server <ip>:<my-local-port>;
}
```

Then a server to upgrade the http connection to websocket:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
   default upgrade;
   '' close;
}
server {
   listen 8020;
      location / {
         proxy_pass http://websocket;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
   }
}
```

[Source](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)